# WebRequest returns different href attribute values then browser does

Tags: c#, html

i want to download html files with resources via C# app. When i try to download page "www.autocont.cz", it changes some href values:

`<link href="/(X(1)S(uonhh5kpvq0fdcxuh4pytyph))/Content/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

Original line from browser view:

`<link href="/Content/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

I found out it differs a bit with different UA.

What can i do to get same result as browser gets?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: javascript changing the link?

Comment: Try setting the user agent string to one a browser uses.

Comment: Can i avoid changing the link? Setting any UA just make another random values in S(random_values)

Comment: Compare the http headers in WEbrequest and browser using a sniffer like wirewhark or fiddler.  The header will determine the href that is returned.  Make the webrequest headers look like the browser headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably some client-side execution done on the href values to give the browser output. Try making use of the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control to get the exact browser output for that html resource.

```
 string getBrowserText(string path) {
    WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
    browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
    browser.AllowNavigation = true;
    browser.Navigate(path);
    bool completed = false;
    browser.DocumentCompleted += (sender, e) => completed = true;
    while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
    while (!completed) ;
    string doctext = ((WebBrowser)browser).DocumentText;
    return doctext;
 }
```

That should return the browser rendition of the html resource. You should probably execute that in a thread or something.

Comment: Sir, thank you. It works, you have saved me a lot of time. However i need to use it in C# library, used by WPF app, so i need to find a way how to do it without referencing Windows.Forms. I am afraid that someone who will check the code might found it wrong. Again thanks a lot.